# trying to scale jquery panel toggler with position:absolute to my webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, slidetoggle

I used `position:absolute;` so that when you click the tab "Send this page to your email", at the top, the panel goes down and goes over the content underneath instead of pushing them down. However, using absolute position means that the tab will move to the left when you zoom in or move to the right when you zoom out. It just doesn't look right when you zoom in or out. I want the tab to "go inwards" when you zoom out and not have it "slide". Is it possible to keep the tab from "sliding" and line it up with panel that slides out?

Here's my page with the tab: http://coroomer.com/apartments/ztestpage/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using absolute positioning, you don't need to bother with javascript/jQuery. You can just modify your HTML/CSS as follows:
Move this:

```
<p align="center" class="flip" id="toggle">Send this page to your email.</p>
```

so that it's the first child of this:

```
<div style="float: right; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;" 500px="" height:="" id="map_canvas" class="map">
```

In the above div (id="map_canvas"), set overflow to "visible". Then set #toggle's CSS as follows (tweak values to suit your needs):

```
#toggle {
    font-family: segoe ui;
    left: 100px;
    top: -44px;
}
```

If you don't want to go that route (but you really should), you'd have to write a function that fires on window.onresize which sets the #toggle element's position relative to whatever element of your choosing.

Comment: Can you explain what a "first child" is and how exactly am I supposed to do that? I put this into my code and the google map went up into my header: <div style="float: right; position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: visible;" 500px="" height:="" id="map_canvas" class="map">
<p id="toggle" class="flip" align="center">Send this page to your email.</p>
</div>

Comment: With markup languages (like HTML), you often have nested elements, i.e., an element that has another element inside it. These nested elements are "children" of the "parent" element. So, if you have a structure like this, <div><p></p><span></span></div>, <p> and <span> are the children of the <div> element, and <p> is the first child because it's the first element that comes after <div>.

Answer (score 1):

you should use another div with fixed width and set it's position to relative, then when you put this div with aboslute positioning into this relative positioned div it won't move with page resizing